# How to execute an alert when user clicks 5 times on a button?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a following view with some brands.

I want to popup an alert when the user clicks on 5 different brand "follow" buttons. Its like when Twitter asks you to follow 5 people before continuing your registration.

```
<%= link_to(t("Seguir"), new_user_registration_path, class: "float-right button") %>
```

In JS, how can I trigger an alert when any of the buttons in the view is clicked 5 times?

```
<script>
    $(".button").on("click", function(){
       alert("ALERT");
    });
</script>
```

This will trigger an alert every time I click on the button, but I want it to popup only when the user has followed 5 people.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter variable , and update it every time a user clicks it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0 ;
    $("button").click(function(){
        count+=1;
        if (count==5)        
             alert("ALERT!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click 5 times to get ALERT!</button>
```

Comment: Almost there. Its triggering the alert on the first click, not on the 5th one!

Comment: @Gibson hmm r u sure?

Comment: Yes... trying to know why, maybe brackets on the if?

Comment: @Gibson nope , i will post a fiddle

Comment: I guess I'm putting the script in the wrong place. Your answer definitely works. I'll play with it to see if I can get it working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Done, It was a markup problem. Your answer works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var count = 0;
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  if (count < 4) {
    count++;
  } else {
    alert('ALERT');
    count = 0;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button"> teste </button>
```