# How to execute JavaScript code when a user clicks the button multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple task where the text shows up after a user clicks the button 3 times. However, the code does not appear to work as I expected.

I've tried adding double bracket inside the if statement as outlined in the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) without luck and also checked similar questions in Stack Overflow like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769492/how-to-execute-an-alert-when-user-clicks-5-times-on-a-button), but they're using jquery, so I have no idea how it works.

Here's my codes:

```js
function countDown() {
  var currentval = document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML;
  var newval = currentval - 0;
  if (currentval > 0) {
    newval = currentval - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML = newval;
}
if (currentval = 0) {
  document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "You clicked 3 times!;
}
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn" onclick="countDown()">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something important here and I will be appreciated for your guidance.

Comment: `currentval = 0` will always be true, since you are **assigning instead of comparing**. For comparison, use `==` (does not compare type) or `===` (includes type).

Comment: `if (currentval = 0)` is wrong.  `if (currentval == 0)` is correct. Also `var` scope in js is limited to its function or object. so you have no access no `currentval`'s value outside your function. e.g: in your last `if` statement.

Comment: How could I miss that? Okay, It's one thing to write outside the function code which is on me. But, how can you tell if you should use one equal or two equals? I heard that even experienced developers are having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (currentval = 0) {` it should be `if (currentval == 0) {` and your `if` condition is outside of `countDown()` function.

```js
function countDown() {
  var currentval = document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML;
  console.log(currentval);
  var newval = currentval - 0;
  if (currentval > 0) {
    newval = currentval - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML = newval;
  if (currentval == 0) {
    document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "You clicked 3 times!";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn" onclick="countDown()">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors you made have already been mentioned, I just wanted to add an answer with a little more modern and concise code. You really shouldn't use inline eventlisteners like `onclick`, instead use `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener`:

```js
countDownBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (Number(countDownBtn.textContent)) {
    countDownBtn.textContent -= 1;
  }
  if (!Number(countDownBtn.textContent)) {
    countDownBtn.disabled = true;
    newText.textContent = "You clicked 3 times!";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
count = 0
function countDown() {
  var currentval = document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML;
 
  if (count < 3) {
    count = count+1
  }else{
  alert("hi")
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn" onclick="countDown()">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed "=" operator`(currentval == 0)`

```js
 function countDown() {
    var currentval = document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML;
    var newval = currentval - 0;
    if (currentval > 0) {
    newval = currentval - 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("countDownBtn").innerHTML = newval;
    if (currentval == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "You clicked 3 times!;"
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn" onclick="countDown()">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer a more concise code would be:

```js
countDownBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (Number(e.target.innerHTML)) {
    e.target.innerHTML -= 1;
  }else{
    e.target.disabled = true;
    newText.textContent = "You clicked 3 times!";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="countDownBtn">3</button>
<p id="newText"></p>
```